# Exception Thrown java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.logging.Logfactory from Domino OSGi Plugin

Tags: java, servlets, osgi, lotus-domino

I am building an IBM Domino OSGi plugin which packages up a class that entends `HttpServlet`.

I want to make Http calls (`get`, `post`, etc.) from the `Servlet` using `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.2.3` and `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.2.3` (extracted from the OSGi bundles).

I have added the two `jar` files to `domino\jvm\lib\ext`, made the usual changes to `java.policy` file*, and added the jars to the build path.

When I add code to create and use `DefaultHttpClient` the server throws the error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.logging.Logfactory`

I know that logging is a bit of a tricky subject in Domino's java implementation. The curious thing is I have the same code running with a Servlet contained by an NSF which runs just fine. However within my OSGi context it breaks. If I call the servlet using a url that includes say `/log.nsf/` it still breaks.

Any help gratefully received!

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Comment: What does System.getProperty("java.class.path") return?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it works in your NSF implementation but looks like you need **commons-logging-1.1.1.jar**. That should be included in the *httpcomponents* download. Or you can download it from here:

http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi

Comment: It's not that it's missing as such, Domino uses it all over the place :-) I have a feeling it's a specifically IBM Domino related problem possibly related to the behaviour of the ClassLoader or other Security problem.

Comment: At least in agent based solutions I need to add it. And the error message is quite clear. So why not give it a try?

Comment: I have tried it and it hasn't resolved the error.  I think the error itself is not to be taken literally. I think it's more about being denied access to the logging class..

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with org.apache packages before in XPages, basically because they try to log to the file system and the security policy doesn't like that. Adding it as a referenced library etc, it uses the same ClassLoader as the XPages runtime, so tries to use the one from the server, and that's when you get the NoClassDefFoundError.

Tried adding it to the WebContent\WEB-INF\lib folder of your OSGi plugin. Adding it to that path works in an NSF because it uses a different ClassLoader. It could well circumvent the problems you're having in an OSGi plugin as well.